# Inserting Mongo Collection data to an array

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have a variable called

```
var events = [];
```

and a collection called `Events = new Meteor.Collection("events");`

The collection already has data in it such as **eventname**, **starttime** and **endtime**.

Is my syntax correct?

```
var collectEvents = Events.find();
var events = [{
     title: collectEvents[0].eventname,
     start: collectEvents[0].starttime,
     end: collectEvents[0].endtime
}];
```

Does not seem to work, the error is:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` returns a cursor. You need to use [fetch](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) on that cursor, in order to return an array of documents. See the "Find and Fetch" section of [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) for more details.

Here's how your code would look with this fix:

```
var collectEvents = Events.find().fetch();
var events = [{
     title: collectEvents[0].eventname,
     start: collectEvents[0].starttime,
     end: collectEvents[0].endtime
}];
```

Comment: yeah that sorted it out, and also I looped it so all the date in the collection will be display :)

`for (var i = 0; i<collectEvents.length; i++) {
     var events = collectEvents ;
    };`

now the events will get all the documents inside collectEvents . . thanks a lot, case closed